# Spring Rest WS: How to handle multiple XML payloads in single endpoint?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

I'm working on creating a Spring REST WS endpoint(Only a single external url needs to be exposed). Client wants us to acknowledge (200 OK) as soon as we receive the request and process it in the background. Client can send different type of xml payload in request body for different requests. For example: In one request, client can send Employee data to add in xml payload, and in other request they can send Customer Data for further processing.

In simplest solution, we could do:

1. create the JAXB annotated POJOs(Customer, Employee that extend a
   common abstract class; e.g. RequestPayload or something)
   corresponding to each possible xml payload ,
2. Retrieve the xml payload as String on controller, determine the root
   element name ("employee or "customer" ...)  and
3. Use our unmarshaller(created using JAXB) to convert the xml String
   to Employee/Customer POJO instance and store this reference in a
   RequestPayload variable.
4. do the further server-side processing..

Just not sure if this is an elegant solution..

Does spring provide any functionality/extension wrt to MessageConverters that would let us do steps 1-3 in a cleaner/elegant way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You problem look like [EIP](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) [Content-Based Router](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html). Camel can help you to route messages to different endpoint by examines message body in "elegant" way and spring support camel pretty great.

The beauty is camel can separate concern like routing from your business logic and you can add more message format later and don't impact the business logic.

Comment: Thanks for the response Raymond, but I was actually looking for something similar within Spring framework.